# Using Knockout, How do I trigger a function based on an arbitrary value of an observable value?

Tags: knockout.js

I'm new to Knockout and even though I've used an observable pattern library before, I don't know how to set a function to observe a value in the ViewModel and to trigger when that value changes.

The situation is like this:
I'd like a modal popup to be enabled when the value of a dropdown is "other". I'm using the Twitter bootstrap "dropdown" (which is really a list of anchors) and each anchor has a `click` binding to a function on the ViewModel called `setDetail`. `setDetail` sets the value of an observable property called `problem`.

My thinking is to put a function to observe the value of `problem` in order to keep the logic separate. Is there a way to do this or should I put the code in the `setDetail` function?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can explicitly subscribe to an observable.

The documentation is [available here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html), search for Explicitly subscribing to observables.

You would be doing something like:

```
function ViewModel() {
  this.problem = ko.observable();
  this.problem.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    if (newValue === 'other') {
      // trigger modal
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way, given the HTML

```
<div> 
    <select data-bind="options: dropdownOptions, selectedOptions: problem" ></select>        
</div>
```

​

and the javascript..

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.problem = ko.observable();
    this.dropdownOptions = ko.observableArray(["1","2","3","other"]);                        

    this.problem.subscribe((function(selectedOption) {
        if(selectedOption == "other") {
            alert(self.problem());            
        }
    }));
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
​
```

or the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/pb5ja/2/

Comment: I appreciate your answer and it helps in the case where I'm using a `<select>` but in this case I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap "dropdown" which is a list of anchors. Thanks!